# How many possible 2-colorings of a disconnected bigraph?

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a relationship between the number of connected components in a bigraph and the number of possible 2-colorings?

A connected bigraph (i.e. only one component) can be 2-colored in exactly two different ways.  It seems like a bigraph with two components can be 2-colored in four different ways; and three components, eight ways.

This suggests that a bigragph with $n$ components can be 2-colored in $2^n$ ways.  Is that correct?  Does this mean a k-partite graph with $n$ components can be k-colored in $k^n$ ways?

Comment: P.S. I'm a programmer writing a [graph library](https://github.com/jaredbeck/graph_matching), not a mathematician, so apologies if this is too simple of a question or if I botched some terminology. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean a bipartite graph ?
If so, that sounds correct !  No shame in asking.

Though It's only true for $k = 2$.
In general in a $k$-partite graph,
one component can have a lot more than $k$ possible colorings.

Take a triangle and add a vertex $v$ with one single neighbor on this triangle.
It's a 3-colorable component, but for each of the 3 proper 3-colorings of the triangle, $v$ has 2 available colors.  So in total this graph gets 6 colorings.